# How to interpretHTML code inside uib-tooltip

Tags: html, angularjs, translate

After looked for a solution, I have found a lot of article but not a way to do what I want so I'm there.

My problem:
I use uib-tooltip to set some explanation on the use/utility of some fields. I also use $translate with i18n files to do some translation.
These i18n files contains some html codes for special chars (because of servers issue I can't simply use UTF-8...).

And so, when I use simply for exemple:

```
<span translate="create.period"></span>
```

It's working fine, the HTML is interpreted fine and I have the good result.
Exemple of value on my i18n file:

```
create.period:'Ce champ contient la valeur de la p&eacute;riode'
```

Result from the previus code:

```
Ce champ contient la valeur de la période
```

---

But if I use the uib-tooltip I have some issue.
Exemple of my code:

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign pointer signColor' uib-tooltip="{{'create.period' | translate}}"></span>
```

And here the reult on the tooltip popup is :

```
Ce champ contient la valeur de la p&eacute;riode
```

I have seen lot of thing like old way to do (uib-tooltip-html) or way to do with
$sce and ng-bind-html, but I can't do that here because I on the uib-tooltip.

So do I have miss some simple thing? 
Or have you a solution for me? (and explanatinons :p)

Thank you very much !    :)

I add a try for a filter:

```
filter("htmlToPlaintext",  ['$sce', '$compile', function ($sce, $compile) {
return function (val) {
    return $sce.valueOf($sce.trustAsHtml(val));;
};
```

}])

Saddly not worky.

Comment: hi use this `uib-tooltip-html`

Comment: As I said I already see that, but that dosen't work, it's always displays the html code and not the interpreted char :S

Comment: You can try to use `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);`

Comment: Hi, no saddly that doen't work, I already tried taht (and all possible value for this sanitize strategy). :S

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.create.period = $sce.trustAsHtml('Ce champ contient la valeur de la p&eacute;riode');

<a href="#" uib-tooltip-html="create.period">scope variable</a>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign pointer signColor' uib-tooltip-html="create.period"></span>
```

pass '$sce' dependency in your controller

Comment: I don't if it works, but the problem with this solution is that for every key of my translation file I have to create a var on the controller with your solution, that's pretty heavy (I have some pages with big forms and tooltip for each fields, do that produce a looooot of keys). 
But I tried to filter my result with a filter which use $sce.trustAsHtml and that doesn't work.